# how to copy multiple table form server to another server in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, automation

So what Im trying to accomplish here is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OBJECT NAME
FROM DBA_OJECTS@M310
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
AND OWNER ='MSUSER'
=======>  6638

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OBJECT NAME
FROM DBA_OJECTS@M311
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
AND OWNER ='MSUSER'
=======>   3833
```

So there is a difference of 2805 tables that are in M310 that are not in M311 server. I can find out what those tables are by using MINUS function. Without creating all the 2805 tables manually (one by one) how would I go about in doing this.

Comment: sorry, you're asking how to copy 2805 tables from one database to another?

Comment: and just table structures, DDL, or also their data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sqlplus script something like this:

```
set pagesize 0
set linesize 32767
set trimspool on
set timing off
set feedback off
set heading off

spool create_tables.sql

select 'create table '||object_name|| ' as select * from '||object_name||'@M310;'
from
( select object_name from dba_objects@m310 
  where object_type = 'TABLE' and owner = 'MSUSER'
  minus
  select object_name from dba_objects@m311
  where object_type = 'TABLE' and owner = 'MSUSER'
)
;
spool off
```

This will spool a file called 'create_tables.sql' which you can run to create your missing tables. Note that this will populate them too. If you do not want them populated, then  add a "where 1=2", such as...

```
select 'create table '||object_name|| ' as select * from '||object_name||'@M310 where 1=2;'
```